# Как узнать, что пользователь репостнул в историю в ВК?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, вконтакте

Хочу сделать бота для розыгрышей, используя API сообщества. Бот должен проверять, сделал ли пользователь репост определенного поста из группы в свою историю. В API не нашел ничего (возможно, плохо искал), но готов использовать другие способы.

Может, все-таки это возможно реализовать с помощью оф. API? Если, нет то как по-другому это можно сделать?